# debian 9, apt-get install php7.3, you have held broken packages?

Tags: debian, php

I am trying to install php7.3 and nginx on Debian 9.

What does "you have held broken packages" mean and how do I fix it?

Here is what I see (after `sudo su -`)

```bsh
root@vps149861:/etc/apt# apt-get update
Ign:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease  
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release                       
Hit:4 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease               
Hit:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x stretch InRelease
Hit:7 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

root@vps149861:/etc/apt# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@vps149861:/etc/apt# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@vps149861:/etc/apt# apt-get install php7.3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.3 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.3 but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.3-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.3-cgi but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

also I've never used `apt-mark` or if its useful in this situation, but this says:

```bsh
E: No packages found
root@vps149861:/etc/apt# apt-mark showhold
root@vps149861:/etc/apt#
```

also, per request:

```bsh
root@vps149861:/etc/apt# dpkg -l | grep ^h
root@vps149861:/etc/apt#
```

and the `-f` option is also no help to me ...

```bsh
root@vps149861:/etc/apt# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Find the held packages: `dpkg -l | grep ^h`. Add this information to the question.

Comment: there are no held packages

Comment: Hmm strange.  I usually use `aptitude` in interactive mode to resolve such things.

Comment: I believe you would need to choose one of the web implementations to also install (either `libapache2-mod-php7.3`, `php7.3-fpm`, or `php7.3-cgi`).  Though I am not seeing those packages available for Debian 9 so I am not sure where you are getting them from.

Comment: Please show us the output of `apt-cache policy php7.3 libapache2-mod-php7.3 php7.3-fpm php7.3-cgi`. In the [documentation](https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/wiki) of the packages.sury.org repository the FAQ section explains that you have to select a SAPI package (libapache2-mod-php7.3, php7.3-fpm or php7.3-cgi) manually. Actually, you needn't install the dummy php7.3 package at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did and worked perfectly for me.

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude

sudo aptitude install php7.3
```

Comment: Would you mind adding an explanation on why using `aptitude` instead of `apt-get` for package installation would solve the OPs problem?

Comment: "While apt-get would probably die-out in case of conflicting action regarding installation or removal of package with a message, Aptitude can suggest possible measures to remove that conflict. " https://www.tecmint.com/difference-between-apt-and-aptitude/

Comment: I noticed libphp7.3.so not available in /usr/lib/apache2/modules dir - (Debian - Apache). Whenever I was using apt command, it was giving a message as given below:

Comment: `...
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.3 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.3 but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.3-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
                   php7.3-cgi but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Thank you. I was meaning to recommend that you edit your post to include explanations, so that the answer is helpful to as many people with similar problems as possible (and not only the OP of the question).